# visual studio 2012 project deployment

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Ok, this should be a simple one, but despite all of my research I haven't been able to find the answer. I've developed a program in vb.net in VS 2012. I thought that all I had to do was compile the project for release then send the release folder to anyone I wanted to give the project to. However, when someone tries to use my program they get an error stating that the program can't find a .dll that was added as a reference to my project. Sure enough, looking at the error on the user's machine I see the path to the .dll on my machine. Isn't there some setting or something else in Visual Studio 2012 that I need to set that will change this path from being specific to my machine to any machine that this program is copied to? Help?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the DLL reference under `References` in your project. Then set `Copy Local` to `true`.

This should ensure that the DLL will be copied to the output directory.

[image]
[image]